# Deleting documents in a CouchDB database

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using CouchDB to store the ledger of peers in my Hyperledger Fabric network. I want to delete a document in my CouchDB database after a certain expiry time. Also, the expiry time should differ with document i.e. the expiry time should be set when a particular document gets appended to the document.

Comment: CouchDB doesn't have tables or rows. Do you mean databases and documents? And what do you mean by purge? Do you truly want to purge them? This is dangerous, but is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741204/how-to-purge-couchdb-documents). Or do you just want to delete them normally?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the wrong terminology (I'm new to couchdb); I have updated the question. My intent is to normally delete the document based on the expiry time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this automatically in CouchDB. To accomplish the same, you'll need to run a periodic process (perhaps nightly?) that deletes any documents which you wish to expire. Depending on the OS and language you're using, this should be relatively easy to accomplish with a scheduled task or cron job or similar.